# Как расставить запятые в предложениях с уточнениями и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Примеры:

1. Уже давно в саду повсюду беспорядочно валялись ветви деревьев.
2. В саду уже давно повсюду беспорядочно валялись ветви деревьев.
3. Повсюду в саду уже давно беспорядочно валялись ветви деревьев.

Или здесь запятые не нужны? Если нужны, то по каким правилам здесь ставить запятые. По правилам уточняющих и пояснительных оборотов или (и) по правилам однородных (неоднородных) определений (обстоятельств) ? Я не могу понять. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это неоднородные обстоятельства, запятые не нужны.

Смотрим у [Розенталя]  [1](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm):

> Уточнение – это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому, а пояснение – обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.

Например, уточнение могло бы выглядеть так:

> За поместьем, *(где именно за поместьем?)* в саду, уже давно повсюду беспорядочно валялись ветви деревьев.